# How to execute SQL LAG() without being affected by the JOIN clause

Tags: sql, mysql, lag

I need to get the % change in price of a stock for the dates when the company have dividend exdates.

I have these two tables:

Table 1: Get the prices

```
 select *
 from prices_table
 where ticker = 'AAPL-US'
order by date desc
```

Table 2: Get the dividends

```
select *
from dividends
where ticker = 'AAPL-US'
order by exdate desc
```

The dates in the prices table are daily (trading dates) while the dividends table only have rows for dates with dividend exdates.

prices table

| Date | Ticker | Prices |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20240312 | AAPL-US | 172.75 |
| 20240311 | AAPL-US | 170.73 |
| 20240309 | AAPL-US | 169 |

dividends table

| Exdate | Ticker |
| --- | --- |
| 20240209 | AAPL-US |
| 20231110 | AAPL-US |
| 20230811 | AAPL-US |

I tried the below script using lag() however, the issue is instead of getting the price for the previous trading day before the dividend exdate, it gets the price for the previous exdate:

```
 select 
 a.ticker
, a.date
, price as current_price
, lag(price, 1) over(order by date asc) as previous_price
,   round(((price - (lag(price, 1) over(order by date asc))) / 
(lag(price, 1) over(order by date asc)) * 100),2) as pct_chg
from price a
join dividends b on a.ticker = b.ticker
and (a.date = b.exdate)
where a.ticker = 'AAPL-US'
order by a.date desc`
```

data i am expecting:

| ticker | date | current price | previous_price | pct_chg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL-US | 20240209 | 188.85 | 188.32 | 0.28 |
|  |  |  |  |  |

May you please help me with what should I tweak with my script?

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (5-7 rows per table). Provide desired output which matches the sample data completely.

Comment: Will there always be a prices row correlating with the `dividends.exdate`? Similarly for the previous price, will there always be a prices row correlating with `dividends.exdate - 1`?

Comment: The general solution for problems like this due to joins is to use the window function in a subquery or CTE that only uses the main table, then join that with the other table.